How do I run atlantis plan for multiple projects?
I have a service {env}-service --> prod-service | staging-service and I'd like to have atlantis plan for both these services.
Here's the command I tried:
atlantis plan -p staging-service -p prod-service

But -p doesn't take multiple arguments?
I also tried using regex:
atlantis plan -p *staging|prod*-service

But this resulted in only prod-service to be planned.

Is this supported? How can I do it?

Did you find any solutions?

No. You can plan for multiple directories though @AliTou
